# AB bench on Apache server very slow

Tags: mysql, apache, nginx, benchmarking

I made two virtual machines using VirtulBox based on Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS, one with APACHE-MYSQL and another with NGINX-MYSQL. The installed versions are those taken from the standard repository. Now I want tested a local site (the same on the two machines) by using AB. I noted very different results regarding the total time to complete the operation. So these are my results:

APACHE-MYSQL:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.myrestsite.com/device/ 
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.myrestsite.com (be patient).....done

Server Software:        Apache/2.2.22
Server Hostname:        www.myrestsite.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /device/
Document Length:        220 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   50.285 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        17
(Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 17, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      39801 bytes
HTML transferred:       22001 bytes
Requests per second:    1.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5028.547 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       502.855 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.77 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   2.3      0       9
Processing:  5008 5023  25.6   5014    5127
Waiting:        4   17  25.3      8     121
Total:       5008 5024  26.3   5014    5128

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
 50%   5014
 66%   5017
 75%   5021
 80%   5025
 90%   5060
 95%   5091
 98%   5127
 99%   5128
100%   5128 (longest request)
```

NGINX-MYSQL:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.myrestsite.com/device/ 
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.myrestsite.com (be patient).....done

Server Software:        nginx/1.1.19
Server Hostname:        www.myrestsite.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /device/
Document Length:        221 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   0.579 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        90
 (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 90, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      38598 bytes
HTML transferred:       21998 bytes
Requests per second:    172.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       57.887 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.789 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests) 
Transfer rate:          65.11 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
               min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       2
Processing:    17   56  87.0     27     333
Waiting:       17   56  86.9     27     333
Total:         17   57  87.3     27     334

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
 50%     27
 66%     30
 75%     34
 80%     39
 90%    271
 95%    322
 98%    331
 99%    334
100%    334 (longest request)
```

It's normal that the same request needs 50.285 seconds on APACHE and 0.579 seconds on NGINX? Is possible such a difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: Your apache tests show 17 failures, your nginx tests 90! If a test needs just a few msec to fail, but several seconds to complete, this could explain quite nicely why apache takes longer.

Comment: Maybe...but I made the same test three times on NGINX with 15-18 failures and approx 0.30 ms to complete. More or less failures, the difference about the total time needed to complete doesn't change after all.